# A theorem for n similar n-gons

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

When I studied [the conjecture 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447773/two-conjectures-of-four-squares), I found a generalization:

**Conjecture:** Let $A_{i1}A_{i2}...A_{in}$ for $i=1,2,..,n$ be a regular n-gons, such that $A_{i1} \rightarrow A_{i2} \rightarrow ....\rightarrow A_{in} $ all counter clockwise, (or all clockwise). Let $G_j$ be the centroids of n-polygon $A_{1j}A_{2j}...A_{nj}$ for $j=1,2,...,n$. Then show that: $G_1G_2...G_n$ is a regular n-gon. In the figure as attachted n=6.

[image]

**A generalization:** Let $A_{i1}A_{i2}...A_{in}$ for $i=1,2,..,n$ be $n$ similar n-gons, such that $A_{i1} \rightarrow A_{i2} \rightarrow ....\rightarrow A_{in} $ all counter clockwise, (or all clockwise). Let $G_j$ be the centroids of n-polygon $A_{1j}A_{2j}...A_{nj}$ for $j=1,2,...,n$. Then show that: $G_1G_2...G_n$ form a $(n+1)$ th similar n-polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/n}$. Then there are complex numbers $z_k$ and $c_k$ with
$$A_{kj}=z_k+c_k\omega^j\quad(1\leq k\leq n, \ 1\leq j\leq n)\ ,$$
and your "averaged polygon"  has vertices
$$G_j:={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj}={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n z_k+\left({1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\right)\>\omega^j\ .$$
This shows that the "averaged polygon" is again regular.

The "generalization" can be handled similarly: Begin with
$$A_{kj}=z_k+c_k w_j\quad(1\leq k\leq n, \ 1\leq j\leq n)\ .$$
Here $z_k$ is the centroid of the $k^{\rm th}$ polygon, the $c_k$ are complex stretching factors, and the $w_j$ with $\sum_{j=1}^n w_j=0$ determine the common shape of the polygons.

Comment: Dear @ChristianBlatter , 

More generalization: Let $A_{i1}A_{i2}...A_{in}$ for $i=1,2,..,m$ be $m$ similar direction n-gons. Let $G_j$ be $n$ centroids of m-gons $A_{1j}A_{2j}....A_{mj}$ for $j=1,2,...,n$. Then $G_1G_2...G_n$ form a $(m+1)$th similar n-polygon.