# N-squares conjecture

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

When I studied [the conjecture 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447773/two-conjectures-of-four-squares),  I found a generalization as follows:

**Conjecture:** Let $A_iB_iC_iD_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$ be $n$ squares in a plane, with $A_i \rightarrow B_i \rightarrow C_i \rightarrow D_i \rightarrow A_i$ all counter clockwise, (or all clockwise) for $i=1,2,...,n$. Then show that:
$$Area(A_1A_2...A_n)+Area(C_1C_2...C_n)=Area(B_1B_2...B_n)+Area(D_1D_2...D_n)$$

See the conjecture in [GeoGebra](http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1678209)

[image]